# Testing multiple URLs using Nightwatchjs & Request

Tags: node.js, request, nightwatch.js

I'm using the **Request** package with my **Nightwatchjs** setup to test the status codes of a number of URLs (about 50 in total).

My issue is twofold.

Firstly, my code is currently as such (for a single URL);

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports = {
    'Status Code testing': function (statusCode, browser) {
        request(browser.launch_url + browser.globals.reviews + 'news/', function (error, response, body) {
            browser.assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200);
        });
    },
};
```

but it's failing with a

> ✖ TypeError: Cannot read property 'launch_url' of undefined

So my **first** question is, how can I incorporate ***browser.launch_url + browser.globals.reviews + 'news/'*** into the script for a request?

**Secondly**, I have a list of about 50 URLs that I need to test the status code of.

Rather than repeat the code below 50 times, is there a more succinct, readable way of testing these URLs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct call you should be making is `browser.launchUrl` to access the API then you can concatenate the appending string paths.

Also, I believe you may be mistaking the purpose of Nightwatch.  Nightwatch isn't an API testing tool, it's used to test UI as it relates to end-to-end testing.  While you can incorporate some data validation to supplement your UI testing with Nightwatch, there are better options out there.  But your question was how to do so with Nightwatch, so you don't have to repeat it over and over again.  I created a function for my GET requests and a separate function for my POST requests.  My get functions would pass in a token for authentication, and my POST requests would pass in a token as well as the payload (in my case JSON).  Hope this helps you out